# How to fill in rows with previous non-null value?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this -

```
ID|Month|MyValue
1|202212|null
1|202211|bbb
1|202210|null
1|202209|null
1|202208|aaa
```

What is an efficient way to update the `MyValue` column with the previous non-null value?

So the above table becomes

```
ID|Month|MyValue
1|202212|bbb
1|202211|bbb
1|202210|aaa
1|202209|aaa
1|202208|aaa
```

Comment: `I am looking for a very performant approach` ... then fix your data at its source

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not an option unfortunately, source team isn't making any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to find the most recent non-null value for each row.
Try a query like that:

```
UPDATE 
  table_1 t1
SET t1.MyValue = (
    SELECT 
      t2.MyValue
    FROM 
      table_2 t2
    WHERE 
      t2.ID = t1.ID 
      AND t2.Month < t1.Month 
      AND t2.MyValue IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY 
      t2.Month DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE 
  t1.MyValue IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you out.

```
select ID, 
       Month,
       last_value( MyValuenum ignore nulls) over (order by Month desc)
from my_data;
```